# grails 2.0.0.RC1 app fails on Ubuntu

Tags: grails, ubuntu, groovy

I have a Grails 2.0.0.RC1 app that works fine on Windows. However, when I try to run it under Ubuntu, I get the following error message whenever I try to load a page:

```
Class
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
Message
    No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes 
    outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the 
    originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request 
    and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of 
    DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or 
    RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I'm slightly surprised by `DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet` in the message above, because I'm not using portlets in this app.

Also, when I start the app, I see lots of log messages like the following that don't appear when run under Windows:

```
DEBUG resource.ResourceTagLib - Resource: /images/tab_l.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer
DEBUG resource.ResourceTagLib - Resource: /images/tab_r.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer
DEBUG resource.ResourceTagLib - Resource: /images/tab_m.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer
```

Comment: The message mentions DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet only because apparently this issue can arrise in both context. With grails you are indeed using DispatcherServlet under the hood so you can ignore the mention of DispatcherPortlet

Answer (score 3):

I think you're facing this bug: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-111 . It is a bug on resources plugin that is installed by default in grails 2 applications. Problem lies within web.xml - "grailsWebRequest" filter-mapping should be first in list. Check bug description for details.

There are two ways to workaround this bug - uninstall resources plugin or edit web.xml on deployed application by hand and move "grailsWebRequest" filter-mapping as the first one.

I don't know what's the problem with disposition image comment though.